# Flutter context.findRenderObject() returns null

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am trying to do some Gesture motion logic based on the size of a widget.

To get the size, I am calling the following code in the build method...

```
final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
```

This is sometimes returning null?

What is causing this to return null? Is there a more reliable way to get the size of a Widget?

Comment: The example you gave me could work, but for more advanced motion tracking I would need to write a custom class to encapsulate additional data to notify (position, up/down/drag, etc). In addition I would have to maintain motion state in the CustomPainter class and do motion logic in the paint() method. I am just hoping there is a more elegant solution. Maybe there isn't....

Comment: so use `LayoutBuilder` but honestly i have no idea how it helps you when you know the canvas size - anyway you need to interact with `CustomPaint` after any event detected with `GestureDetector` - how you want to do that?

Comment: The common parent stateful widget of the CustomPaint and the GestureDetector maintains state, and GestureDetector callbacks call setState. The changes are then reflected in the CustomPaint.

Comment: so you are rebuilding from scratch your `CustomPainer` after any event detected - for example if you have `onPanUpdate` your `CustomPainter` will be rebuild 20-30 or more times per second

Comment: Yes that is the current way I am doing it. For me, based on the frameworks I have used in the past, and based on the classes exposed by flutter, it is not obvious at all the proper way of doing this for me.

Comment: well, as i said, if you just want the size use `LayoutBuilder` - here `constraints.biggest` will contain your size

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

You need to make sure the widget is currently being rendered (for example, on screen) or give it a time to render before trying to access it, for example, by calling this on your `initState()` if this is from a Stateful Widget:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(() {
   final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
});
```

Comment: I need the size in the build method of the Widget. This will not work for that will it?

Comment: You can't have the `size` before painting it, if it's going to be dynamic. But you can have it after the 1st frame, which means that you _at most_ lose one frame before having the size.

Answer (score 0):

```
RenderBox? _initializedRenderBox;
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _initializedRenderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

You can use an instance variable to assign the `RenderBox` and use it later in the `build` function.

Note that call `setState` to make the call of `build` again after getting the `_initializedRenderBox`.